# AC_CHECK_LIB fails in mingw64

Tags: c++, mingw, autotools

I have successfully compiled a library `bc-crypto-base`. In the next step I also successfully compiled and ran an executable dependent on the library.

Now I would like to add an intermediate step of checking the library with `AC_CHECK_LIB`

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([bc-crypto-base], [crc32n], [], [
  echo "### Error! libbc-crypto-base not installed"
  exit -1
  ])
```

The error I get is

```
configure:3540: checking for crc32n in -lbc-crypto-base
configure:3565: clang -o conftest.exe  -I/home/bc-seedtool-cli/sysroot/include   -L/home/bc-seedtool-cli/sysroot/lib conftest.c -lbc-crypto-base   >&5
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld: C:/msys64/home/bc-seedtool-cli/sysroot/lib/libbc-crypto-base.a(crc32.o): in function `crc32n':
C:\msys64\home\bc-seedtool-cli\deps\bc-crypto-base\src/crc32.c:42: undefined reference to `__imp_htonl'
```

This (imo) means that `AC_CHECK_LIB` when compiling a test program does not see `-lws2_32`. How can I tell AC_CHECK_LIB explicitly to link against `-lws2_32`?

Answer (score 1):

Well that was embarrassing:

AC_CHECK_LIB([bc-crypto-base], [crc32n], [], [
echo "### Error! libbc-crypto-base not installed"
exit -1
], [-lws2_32])